# How to log slf4j to a file in cuba Framework

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, cuba-platform

I'm trying to configure cuba framework in order to write the logs in a file, but at the moment I cannot.

I have in the java files:

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BlisterauftragServiceImpl.class);
LOG.info("This is a, info log");
```

In the build.gradle file I have:

```
logbackConfigurationFile = 'etc/war-logback.xml'
```

Then in the folder etc, I have the file war-logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration debug="false" packagingData="true">

    <property name="logDir" value="${app.home}/logs"/>

    <appender name="File" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logDir}/app.log</file>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${logDir}/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread%X{cubaApp}%X{cubaUser}] %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
        <appender-ref ref="File"/>
    </root>

    <!-- Begin CUBA -->

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba" level="DEBUG"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.core.sys" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.core.sys.CubaDefaultListableBeanFactory" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.core.app.scheduling" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.web.sys" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.portal" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.restapi.sys" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.core.app.LockManager" level="INFO"/>

    <!-- End CUBA -->

    <logger name="eclipselink" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="eclipselink.sql" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="org.activiti" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="freemarker" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.docx4j" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="org.xlsx4j" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="WARN"/>

    <logger name="sun" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="com.sun" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="javax" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.atmosphere" level="INFO"/>

    <logger name="org.docx4j.utils.ResourceUtils" level="ERROR"/>

    <logger name="org.docx4j.Docx4jProperties" level="ERROR"/>

    <logger name="org.xlsx4j.jaxb.Context" level="ERROR"/>

    <!-- Begin Perf4J  -->

    <appender name="PerfStatFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logDir}/perfstat.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${logDir}/perfstat.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CoalescingStatistics" class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="60000"/>
        <appender-ref ref="PerfStatFile"/>
    </appender>

    <appender name="UIPerfStatFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logDir}/perfstat-ui.log</file>
        <append>true</append>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${logDir}/perfstat-ui.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="UICoalescingStatistics" class="org.perf4j.logback.AsyncCoalescingStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="120000"/>
        <appender-ref ref="UIPerfStatFile"/>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CoalescingStatistics"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.haulmont.cuba.gui.logging.UIPerformanceLogger" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="UICoalescingStatistics"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- End Perf4J  -->

</configuration>
```

If I change anything in this file, it don't do anything. For example I have tried to change:

```
<file>${logDir}/app.log</file>
```

to:

```
<file>${logDir}/app1.log</file>
```

Then in th folder deploy/tomcat/conf, I find a file logback.xml. In the folder deploy/tomcat/logs, I will find all my logs. I can change the conf files and that will work fine. But my file war-logback is not taken into account.

Then my problem is that deploy folder is created a overrited each time new. Then I have to rewrite le logback.xml file each time the code is regenerated.

Any ideas why is it so?

Thanks
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

logback tries to find configuration as the fllowing steps:

1. Logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath.
4. If no such file is found, service-provider loading facility (introduced in JDK 1.6) is used to resolve the implementation of com.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator interface by looking up the file META-INF\services\ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator in the class path. Its contents should specify the fully qualified class name of the desired Configurator implementation.
5. If none of the above succeeds, logback configures itself automatically using the BasicConfigurator which will cause logging output to be directed to the console.

and you will find it [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration)

so, let's make sure the configuration file in your war is named "logback-test.xml","logback.groovy" or "logback.xml", maybe that's why "war-logback.xml" was ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to permanently override the development logging configuration, then
create a file `<project_name>/etc/logback.xml` and put your configuration in it.
After running the `deploy` task, the file will be copied to `<project_folder>/deploy/app_home/logback.xml`.